# Excel spreadsheet went small

Tags: microsoft-excel, zoom

I was typing in Excel and my fingers hit something and the screen went so small I can't read it. What could I have hit to make this happen?

It seems that I am always hitting something and the screen I am working on does something crazy. I need to know how to get back to the way it was previously.  I have hit the arrow what is undo, but nothing happens. I am typing on a laptop. Someone suggested that I get a regular keyboard and connect to my laptop.

HELP!!! I am not very good on the mechanics of a computer. I need help for a Senior (OLD) lady!!!

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption this is just a very low Zoom, try pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>J</kbd> to reset zoom level to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Or another way to enlarge the Word/Excel screen is on your bottom right hand side you can see the zoom box you can make to 100% or above as per your convenience.

[image: Excel zoom scroll bar]